# How to access links in the specific section of links through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

In a web page , I see three h3 tags , and each h3 tag contains few links.

My scenario is : I want to go to one of the h3 tag and count the links only in that section and each of them.

Can anyone tell me how to click links of that specific section ?

Comment: can you please share html code section please?

Comment: </ul>
        <h3>Quick Links ofHyderabad</h3>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="/hyderabad/restaurant-quicklinks/dinner-favourites" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Dinner Favourites">Dinner Favourites</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/hyderabad/restaurant-quicklinks/pocket-friendly" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="Pocket Friendly">Pocket Friendly</a></li>
 </ul>

Comment: @naazneen3264 - I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Please post the HTML in the question, properly formatted, instead of the image. At some point in the future, the image will no longer be available and this question will be less valuable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
List <WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[text()='Quick Links ofHyderabad']/following::ul/a"));
int noOfLinks = we.size();

// To click on all the links just use a `for` loop
for(WebElement w : we) {
    w.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize the code as per your need. It should be something like this:

```
//Pick all div elements:
List< IWebElement > elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(//div[contains(@class, 'description')]/h3));

// Now use a forloop to go through each element and grab the data you need.
String Data = elements.getText();

// Split the Data using regex and get the count as per your html code
```